# GPON using an SFP module

Tags: home-networking

I have the TP-Link [ER7212PC](https://www.tp-link.com/my/business-networking/omada-sdn-router/er7212pc/) router connected to the ISP using TP-Link GPON Terminal [XZ000-G3](https://www.tp-link.com/baltic/service-provider/gpon/xz000-g3/)

To setup the PON connection I copied the serial number from the ISP router.

The router I have (ER7212PC) has an SFP port, which makes me think I can buy an SFP transceiver (should be single mode, with an SC connector) and plug that directly to the router.

Instead of doing:

> Fiber Cable -> GPON Terminal -> Router

Do:

> Fiber Cable -> GPON SFP Module -> Router

Is there such an SFP module (1G should suffice)? One that can replace the GPON terminal?
Would I be able to "change" its serial like I did? Or I can provide the ISP with the SFP GPON serial?

Comment: Not supposed to ask for recommendations. However, what you are looking for is a sfp which has a mac and supports the G.984 standard, https://www.fs.com/uk/products/133619.html may do what you need as will others. Doing a search will bring up info on how to access and configure it. In theory, you should get permission from your isp.

Comment: Thanks. BTW there is a small paragraph there which says:
"Note: If you need to change the SN code on the product label to your registered SN code, please contact us"

Comment: Ignore that. Once you ssh into the device, you issue a single command which changes it - `set_serial_number ABCD12345678`. See https://hack-gpon.github.io/ont-fs-com-gpon-onu-stick-with-mac/ for other potential changes. You do not need them to do any customisation.

Comment: Thank you!! Not sure I understand how to SSH into something like that..?

After its connected to my TP-Link Router..?

Comment: You assign an IP address to the cage - say 192.168.1.2, then ssh into .1. The username & password are readily available.